# remove enclosing brackets from a file

Tags: unix-text-processing

How can I efficiently remove enclosing brackets from a file with bash scripting (first occurrence of `[` and last occurrence of `]` in file)?
All brackets that are nested within the outer brackets and may extend over several lines should be retained.
Leading or trailing whitespaces may be present.

content of `file1`

```
[
  Lorem ipsum
  [dolor] sit [amet
  conse] sadip elitr
]
```

`cat file1 | magicCommand`

desired output

```
  Lorem ipsum
  [dolor] sit [amet
  conse] sadip elitr
```

---

content of `file2`

```
  [Lorem ipsum [dolor] sit [amet conse] sadip elitr]
```

`cat file2 | magicCommand`

desired output

```
  Lorem ipsum [dolor] sit [amet conse] sadip elitr
```

Comment: So the ones you want removed are always the first and last characters of the file (Not counting leading/trailing whitespace)?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit the file to remove the braces, use `ed`:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '1s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\[/\1/' '$s/\]\([[:space:]]*\)$/\1/' w | ed -s file1
```

If you want to pass on the modified contents of the file to something else as part of a pipeline, use `sed`:

```sh
sed -e '1s/^\([[:space:]]*\)\[/\1/' -e '$s/\]\([[:space:]]*\)$/\1/' file1
```

Both of these will, for the first line of the file, remove a `[` at the start of the line (Skipping over any initial whitespace before the opening brace), and for the last line of the file (Which can be the same line as in your second example), remove a `]` at the end of the line (Not counting any trailing whitespace after the close bracket). Any leading/trailing whitespace will be preserved in the result; use `s/...//` instead to remove them too.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s*\[\s*//; s/\s*\]\s*$//' file
```

That's aggressive about removing *all* whitespace around the outer brackets, which isn't exactly what you show in your desired output.

Comment: as I do not need the leading or trailing whitespaces your solution is also exciting, especially as it is even shorter than using `sed` ... thanks

Comment: This will be more memory intensive than the sed call: this perl will read the entire file into memory, the sed reads a line at a time. If your files are not large, then this will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed for `-E` and `-z`:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\[(.*)]/\1/' file1

  Lorem ipsum
  [dolor] sit [amet
  conse] sadip elitr
```

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\[(.*)]/\1/' file2
  Lorem ipsum [dolor] sit [amet conse] sadip elitr
```

The above will read the whole file into memory.

Comment: I never noticed the option `-z` before ... thanks for this tip